# Select a row by the value of one cell in jqxGrid

Tags: javascript, php, jqxgrid

I've got a little question about the use of **jqxGrid** from **jqWidgets**.
I'm trying to select a row of my table dynamically from another page. I explain myself:

My **first** page contains a list of users. I want that when I choose an user on this list, it opens a new page with, by exemple, **the ID of my user returned in GET through PHP**. And then, I want to generate a new grid, with less information, but with the user already selected.

I've found how to select a row by her index *`$('#grid').jqxGrid('selectrow', 10);`* but it's not working, because if one table is sorted or filtered, the index is changed...

So, is there any way to do this ?

Here's the code wich is called when selecting a row on first table:

```
$('#search_right').bind('rowselect', function(event){
    var iSocID = $('#search_right').jqxGrid('getcellvalue', event.args.rowindex, 'id');
    $("#soci_right").load('activites/soc.search.php?a=form&id='+iSocID);
    $('#content').jqxTabs('select', 3);
});
```

And here's the generation code of my second list:

```
var url = 'activites/soc.search.php';
    var source = {
        datatype: "json",
                datafields: [
                    { name: 'name', type: 'string'},
                    { name: 'id', type: 'int'},
                ],
                id: 'id',
                url: url,
                root: 'data'
    };

    dataSource = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

    $("#soci_table").jqxGrid({
        source: dataSource,
        theme: jqxGlobalTheme,
        columnsresize: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        showfilterrow: true,
        columns: [
            { text: 'Name', dataField: 'name'},     
            { text: 'ID', dataField: 'id',  hidden:true},
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting the support of jqWidgets (who couldn't help me......) I've made a little snippet that does the tricks... But I think jqWidget should add this as a default functionnality of jqxGrid !

I paste you my code here, hope it'll help some of you !

```
    $('#search_right').bind('rowselect', function(event){
    var iSocID = $('#search_right').jqxGrid('getcellvalue', event.args.rowindex, 'id');

         // Create filter
        var filtergroup = new $.jqx.filter();
        var filtervalue = iSocID;
        var filtercondition = 'EQUAL';

        var filter1 = filtergroup.createfilter('stringfilter', filtervalue, filtercondition);

        var filter_or_operator = 1;
        filtergroup.addfilter(filter_or_operator, filter1);

        $("#soci_table").jqxGrid('addfilter', 'id', filtergroup);

        // Apply filter

        $("#soci_table").jqxGrid('applyfilters');

        // Select row

        $('#soci_table').jqxGrid('selectrow', 0);

        // Remove filter

        $("#soci_table").jqxGrid('clearfilters');
    });
```